# Why is my React App showing bootstrap navbar vertically?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to write a react app with authentication. So some of the fields on the navbar would be showed only to authenticated users. For this purpose I have a Navbar.jsx file and a SignedInLinks.jsx file.

My NavBar.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Signedinlinks from "./SignedInLinks";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-default navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div className="container">
        <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">
          RS
        </Link>
        <Signedinlinks />
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

My SignedInLinks.jsx:

```
import React from "react";

import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Signedinlinks = () => {
  return (
    <ul className="navbar-nav">
      <li className="nav-item">
        <NavLink to="/">Edit Blogs</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <NavLink to="/">Edit Photographs</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <NavLink to="/" className="btn btn-primary">
          RS
        </NavLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Signedinlinks;
```

I'm using the following for css in index.html:

```
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
 />
```

And the index.css has :

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}
```

Any idea why my navbar items are showing in a Vertical list?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Navbar doesn't contain one of the `navbar-expand*` classes. [Read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#how-it-works)...

> *"Navbars require a wrapping .navbar with
>   .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl} for responsive collapsing and color
>   scheme classes."*

Also, there is no `navbar-default` in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be working now. I had tried earlier with navbar-expand, but it didn't change, i guess it needed to refresh once.

Answer (score 1):

It's for the responsiveness. you can overwrite the "flex-direction: row;" style in your "" component that will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just Add the stylesheet `<link>` into your `<head>`

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Hi @Silvi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Glad that you're trying to help here. I would suggest you to please go through the question including the libraries, plugins, framework with their versions the author is using and try to be more clear in your answer as to why and how it can be resolved using your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and then read Silvi's answer which caused me to track down this missing bit from my App.js:

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Adding that fixed this issue for me.